# Why is my backend console errors giving me errors regarding my front end

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mern

[image: Console Error image]

Getting an error saying i cant use import regarding my front end code when im trying to run node index.... i havent had this issue till now when i just got back to this project.

I already have type": "module", insde my pacakage.json for my backend folder.
im just a little confused why its giving me a syntax error in my backend console for code thats in my front end client folder
I tried   "type": "module", in my front ends package.json but then that causes issues with my front end code and wont run things.

Comment: Can you put some of the code from Post.js here?

Answer (score 0):

Since react is written with JSX, you need to transpile the JSX into javascript. Trying to run a JSX file with node is going to result in an error because node will only run plain javascript. It may be a bit difficult to set up a transpiler like babel, so it is recommended that you use the `create-react-app` command in the terminal.

`npx create-react-app nameofmy-app`

and then to run the app:

`npm start`

This will start the build process, which will transpile your JSX into javascript, and then run a server that you can access in the browser.

After creating this new react app you will have to import your react files from your previous project directory.

Comment: im not trying to run any jsx files with my server. my client and server folders are completely different so im confused on why when trying to start my server its trying to look at code in another folder

Comment: How long has it been since you stopped working on this project and then came back to it?

Comment: last time i worked on this was 2 days ago when it was working past two days getting same error :( might just start a whole new project with the same code see if it gives same error

Comment: do you have a github repository I could clone?

Comment: I just ended up going back to a commit thats working. Thank you for the help. Weird bug.